# How to stop a decreasing iteration after xth element?

Tags: php, for-loop, iteration

So I have a for loop that is decreasing...

```
for ($i=count($array); i>0; $i--;)
{
 if(condition)
 {DO SOMETHING like print the element in a decreasing manner}
 if(enter ending iteration condition here after xth element) break;
}
```

that pretty much sums up my question. How do I formulate the ending iteration - let's say after 5 elements printed I want to stop the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j = 0;
for ($i=count($array); $i>0; $i--)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        DO SOMETHING like print the element in a decreasing manner;
        $j++;
    }
    if($j > 4){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the count of the loop. Instead of decreasing, try to increase so you will have a count of how many items are being printed.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        /* DO SOMETHING like print the element in a decreasing manner */
    }

    /* replace (nth) with the needed number */
    if($i === (nth)) break;
}
```

Comment: `$i` will count the number of elements in the array, not the number being printed.  Unless the first `if` condition is always true, this will be a problem.

Comment: Also note `if($i = (nth)) break;` is an assignment operator, you probably meant `if($i == (nth)) break;`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the limit based on the count, like:

```
$loop_limit = 5;
$array_count = count($array);
$last = $array_count - $loop_limit;

for ($i = $array_count; $i >= $last ; --$i) {
    if ( $i == $last ) {
            //Do whatever you need at this point
    }
    //do the normal loop action
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Caught that after I posted.

Comment: Updated answer. Setting your `for` parameters before initializing it is a huge performance boost when the parameters are the same on each loop (avoids the control structure from having to derive the value for every cycle). And using simple subtraction avoids the need for a loop counter or `break` (though either is fine if your breaking condition were based on something more complicated or unknown, like "break once x number of 'members of type' are processed, etc").